# Code to convert LabVIEW data type to C# data type

Tags: c#, asp.net, labview

I want to know how to convert LabVIEW data types to .net data types.

I am calling a labview dll from my ASP.net code as follows.

```
 LVerr = VIServerLib.OpenReference(path, false, out RefVI);
```

and the DLL is as follows

```
 public static ErrorCluster OpenReference(LVPath path, bool reentrant, out VI vIRef);
```

It seems that we can call LabVIEW unique data type directly (For example VIpath, True/False, Error Cluster and so on).
    But I have no idea how to convert these Lab View data type to C# data type (For example, to strings, TRUE/FALSE, accessing to each element of cluster).

Answer (score 0):

give a look to the example shipped with Labview named "**External Code (DLL)**".

It demonstrates how to interface data types between external code (DLLs) and LabVIEW with the Call Library Function Node.

It is not for C#, but it should be a good starting point.